# Instantiating tag of jsp 2.0 in java code

Tags: java, jsp, tags

I am migrating my java web-application project from JSP to thymeleaf.

I want temporarily to have ability to reuse some simple custom JSP tags in thymeleaf pages. It seems not a problem with custom tags defined in old fashion, as java files. I just instantiate tag, set fake PageContext, request and response, attribtes - and call doStartTag / doEndTag.

However I could not find a way how to instantiate object representing JSP 2.0 tag (i.e. defined in a ".tag" file. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

It looks there are two ways:

1. Use jspc-maven-plugin to get precompiled classes from jsp and tag files - I checked that works - however latest version of this plugin is 2.0-alpha-3 and it is 4 years old now.
2. Access servlet-container jsp compiler (in most cases jasper) and do the same thing as in first variant, but on demand, in execution time. However, this makes application container-dependent.

(My personal opinion now is that it would better to avoid the idea at whole - all solutions looks too unreliable to use in production)